# DataGridView Prevent Formatting

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, visual-studio-2015

Hello again I am trying to get the value of a Cell in DGV (`datagridview`)
but i noticed it was returning a truncated an Rounded up Value.

```
Value in Cell = 32.71529844248667 
but Returned Value = 32.7152984424867
```

the code i am using

```
  Dim data As String = DGV.Item("latitude", DGV.CurrentRow.Index).Value
    MsgBox(data)
```

Cant seem to be able to fix it even by setting formatting to none. Any ideas or can you point me in right direction? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the data type of the value in the cell?  Is it `Double`, `Decimal`, `String` or something else?  Are you saying that the grid was displaying what you expected but the message box was not or that the grid wasn't either?

Comment: Yes the grid display proper Value in cell but msgBox displays wrong rounded value.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you chose not to answer my first question? I didn't ask it for my health.